# R output row and column index of dataframe with target values in a vector

Tags: r, dataframe

Here I have a dataframe `df`:

```
structure(list(col1 = c("f", "h", "k", "p", "d", "n", "o", "i", 
"s", "a"), col2 = c("e", "d", "m", "g", "r", "h", "k", "p", "t", 
"i"), col3 = c("s", "e", "l", "c", "t", "f", "a", "p", "k", "d"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| f | e | s |
| h | d | e |
| k | m | l |
| p | g | c |
| d | r | t |
| n | h | f |
| o | k | a |
| i | p | p |
| s | t | k |
| a | i | d |

And a vector `vec` containing the values that I would like to search in `df`:

```
vec <- c("a", "h", "ah")
```

I would like to output the column and row index of the element in the vector, with the first column being the element, the second column being the row index and the third column being the column index, like the following (the order of rows are not important), also, it should also take care of values not present in `df`:

```
name row col
h    2   1
h    6   2
a    7   3
a    10  1
ah   NA  NA
```

I tried doing it with `which` or `arrayInd`, but it misses the final record of "a" (note the final row in the first column in `df`), also it throws an error at values (e.g. "ah") not present in `df`.

```
arrayInd(which(df == vec), dim(df), useNames = T)

which(df == vec, arr.ind = T)

     row col
[1,]   2   1
[2,]   6   2
[3,]   7   3
```

Also, I need to effectively add a column of "a" or "h" to the output. Note that I do not know the number of elements in `vec`, it can be 2 or 10 or more, I also don't know how many columns are in `df`, but their column names have the pattern `col{n}`.

Any ideas will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a base R solution.

You can use `arr.ind` inside `which`. You would need to do this for each element in `vec`, so need to wrap it in an `lapply` and `rbind` the results:

```r
do.call(rbind, lapply(vec, function(x) {
  y <- which(df == x, arr.ind = TRUE)
  if(length(y) == 0) y <- cbind(row = NA, col = NA)
  data.frame(name = x, y)}))
#>   name row col
#> 1    a  10   1
#> 2    a   7   3
#> 3    h   2   1
#> 4    h   6   2
#> 5    z  NA  NA
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(purrr)

setNames(vec, vec) |>
  map(~{df == .x}) |>
  map(~which(.x, arr.ind = T)) |>
  map(~if(nrow(.x) == 0) rbind(.x, NA) else .x) |>
  map_dfr(data.frame, .id = "name")

#> name row col
1    a  10   1
2    a   7   3
3    h   2   1
4    h   6   2
5   ah  NA  NA
```